# How can I pass a parameter only if it's true?

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
export function filterClauseJld(operator: Operator, value: QueryPart | QueryPart[]): Clause {
    return {
        '@type': 'clause',
        'op': operator,
        ...assignIf(operator === Operator.Not, {
            value,
        }),
        ...assignIf(operator !== Operator.Not, {
            values: value,
        }),
    }
}
```

Now I want to pass `value` like so:

```
filterClauseJld(Operator.And, [someValue, anotherValue, someotherValue])
```

However, any passed item in the `value` array that I pass might be `undefined`. Is there a good way to only pass the value if it's not `undefined` without doing something like this:

```
    if (!someValue && !anotherValue) {
      filterClauseJld(Operator.And, [someotherValue])
    } else if (!someValue && !someotherValue) {
      filterClauseJld(Operator.And, [another Value])
    }...
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, arguments that aren't provided will end up being `undefined`, so you might as well pass in `undefined`. But I'm not certain on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `undefined` values from the array before passing in the function by using `typeof`, it wouldn't remove some valid values like `0`, `""`, etc :

```
filterClauseJld(Operator.And, [someValue, anotherValue, someotherValue].filter(x => typeof x !== 'undefined'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this :

```
var args = [
    a ?? undefined,
    b ?? undefined,
    c ?? undefined,
].filter(arg => !!arg || arg === null);
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple solution would be to you can use `|` operator

here's an example:

```
const a = undefined;
const b = 10;
const c = 20;

function sum(a, b){
    return a + b;
}

sum(a | c, b); // 30
```

this means if a is undefined use c in its place.
You can read more about logical assignment operators [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to filter your array :

```
var filtered = array.filter(function (val) {
  return val != undefined;
});
```

You can get rid of all the undefined values and then pass it to your function.

Comment: /!\ Type coercion alert by the Loose Equality Police: [`null != undefined` is `false`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) /!\